# Remove specific identical subsequent values in Python list

Tags: python, list

I have the list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3]
```

and want to obtain:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3]
```

That is I don't want any `4`s in my list that are next to each other.

How do I do this without importing any packages?

Comment: Can you share any attempts of your own? What's the problem you have with solving this task? Do you know how `for` and `range` work? Do you know how to remove elements from a list? There are many possible aspects here, so it would be helpful if you update your question with some piece of code that's not working for you.

Comment: So you could have [1,2,3,3,4,5,4]. Also please add some code

Answer (score 1):

```
In [289]: L = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,2,3,3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [290]: answer = [L[0]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [291]: for n in L[1:]: 
     ...:     if n == answer[-1] == 4: 
     ...:         continue 
     ...:     answer.append(n) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [292]: answer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[292]: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3]

l = [l[0]] + [j for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]) if not i == 4 == j]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3]
```

---

Explanation:

This line:

```
[j for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]) if not i == 4 == j]
```

is a list comprehension, where `j` is a variable that iterates through all the values of `l`, excluding the first value, and `i` is the value right before `j` in each iteration.

Only add `j` to the list if the value before it, `i`, os not equal to `4` while `j` is also equal to `4`.

Since `j` omits the first value, concatenate the first value to the beginning of the list with `[l[0]] +` .

Comment: Very nice, thx!